# Computing the value of the passive elements in operational amplifiers

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, amplifier, resistors, circuit-design

In the following circuit R1 = 30 kΩ.

Compute the value of the other passive elements so that:

1. The gain, when active is -3
2. The angular point is in +3 V*

**R2 = ? kΩ**

**Find the value for Vr = ? V**

**R3 = ? kΩ**

[image]

I tried this:

R2 = (R1 * (Av - 1)) / Av

So I think gain is active therefore
R2 = (30 kΩ * (-3 - 1)) / (-3)
R2 = (-60 kΩ) / (-3)
R2 = 20 kΩ?

I think formula for Vr this
Vr = Vin * (R3 / (R1 + R3))

then I need to find Vin and R3
I suppose that VIn = 1
Vr = 1 V * (R3 / (30 kΩ + R3))

And because of angular point Vr = 3?

So I got this:
3 V = 1 V * (R3 / (30 kΩ + R3))
3 V * (30 kΩ + R3) = 1 V * R3
90 kΩ + 3 V * R3 = R3
2 V * R3 = 90 kΩ

R3 = 45 kΩ?
R2 = 20 kΩ?
Vr = 3 V?

Comment: Sorry, we won't do your homework for you. We expect you to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself. Show us all of your work, then as a **specific** question.

Comment: Oh okay, but it is not my homework, I just dont understand what I should do

Comment: Who assigned it to you? Have you tried to simulate it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the behavior of such a circuit.

What is your "angular" point?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The presence of those two diodes forces you to divide the condition of the circuit into different regimes, corresponding to the possible states of forward and reverse bias of the two diodes.

Whether you understand everything that follows depends on your familiarity with the summing, inverting amplifier:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpCQtj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are a few principles that I will rely on in this explanation:

1. The current through RF is equal to the sum of currents through R1 and R3, by KCL. This is the fundamental principle of operation of the summing amplifier. Due to the virtual ground, currents \$I_1\$ and \$I_3\$ are:
   $$ I_1 = \frac{V_{IN} - 0V}{R_1} = \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1}$$
   $$ I_3 = \frac{V_R - 0V}{R_3} = \frac{V_R}{R_3}$$
   This means:
   $$ I_1 + I_3 = \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} + \frac{V_R}{R_3} $$
2. All current \$I_1 + I_3\$ flows through RF, since none flows into or out of the high impedance input of the op-amp. Just for completeness, I'll derive the relationship between inputs \$V_{IN}\$ and \$V_R\$, and output \$V_X\$, which might help, but isn't critical for this answer. By KVL and Ohm's law:
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   I_1 + I_3 &= \frac{0V - V_X}{R_F} \\ \\
   \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} + \frac{V_R}{R_3} &= -\frac{V_X}{R_F} \\ \\
   V_X &= -R_F\left( \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} + \frac{V_R}{R_3} \right)
   \end{aligned}
   $$
3. What *is* critical, is the *direction* of \$I_1 + I_3\$. It will be pivotal in deciding which of the diodes in your circuit is conductive, and which is blocking current.

   - Case A: if current is flowing to the right through RF, then \$I_1 + I_3 > 0\$. In other words:
     $$ \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} + \frac{V_R}{R_3} > 0 $$
   - Case B: if current is flowing to the left through RF:
     $$ \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} + \frac{V_R}{R_3} < 0 $$

Now we are ready to apply these ideas to your own circuit, with the diodes in place:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fstSyn.png)</sup>

For case A, where inputs \$V_{IN}\$ and \$V_R\$ produce a combined current \$I_1 + I_3\$ which flows to the right through any feedback path, D1 blocks, and D2 conducts. All that current flows via R2. By KVL we have:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= 0V - (I_1 + I_3) R_2 \\ \\
&= -R_2\left(\frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} + \frac{V_R}{R_3}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

For case B, where that current flows to the left, D2 blocks, passing no current. All current \$I_1+I_3\$ must be drawn from X via D1 instead. With no current through R2, there's no potential difference across it (by Ohm's law), and OUT must have the same potential as the left end of R2:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= 0V - 0A \times R_2 \\ \\
&= 0V
\end{aligned}
$$

So, this is \$V_{OUT}\$ as a function of \$V_{IN}\$ and \$V_R\$:

$$ V_{OUT} =
\begin{cases}
-R_2\left(\frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} + \frac{V_R}{R_3}\right),  & \text{if } \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} + \frac{V_R}{R_3} > 0 \\
0V, & \text{if } \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} + \frac{V_R}{R_3} < 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

It remains to use these relationships to find suitable input potentials, and resistances to satisfy the conditions you laid out in the original question, which I'll leave up to you.